# Add form-control to all inputs but dropdown with PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the "form-control" class to all my inputs with PHP. I found a solution that works, that's this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_input_class', 'add_wc_input_class' );
function add_wc_input_class($classes) {
  $classes[] = 'form-control';
  return $classes;
}
```

The only problem is, this also adds "form-control" to the dropdown boxes, that makes it look ugly.

[image]

How do I make this only apply to text inputs?

Answer (score -1):

Use Javascript! or better yet, JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[type=text]').addClass('form-control');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It’s not something you use JavaScript for either.

Comment: @Hanobcs So you’re solution is to not use JavaScript, but load an entire **JavaScript library**, just to add a CSS class…? No.

Comment: Just because Bootstrap requires jQuery, doesn’t mean it should be used to apply CSS classes to HTML elements.

Comment: Why? It would actually be easier if he wanted to change. Lots of people are pushing to manage CSS with JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript is _not_ for styling.

Comment: Martin– any ideas for a solution?

Comment: I like how I got downvoted, but nobody came up with a better solution.